# This is related to android studio when I open a new activity

Tags: android-studio-3.0

When I open a new project in android studio then it says us to choose the activity so when I choose empty activity both the part design and text part of my activity_main opens successfully but when choose basic activity the text part of activity.main.xml opens but the design part doesn't open and on the main screen it gives the message 
" Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project”
and the design part is not available for that project...
so how can I solve it.

Comment: Did you install necessary build tools?

Comment: hey I got the solution

Comment: hey you can post your answer so this question would get closed

Comment: Actually It was very simple when we work on android studio and we make some successful projects there comes some updates so when we update our ide it becomes available for us.

Comment: Gotcha, a tip, never update android studio while working on production apps.